# Render :collection wrap each item?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently I'm using:

```
<% @items.each do |item| %>
  <li class="list-item">
    <%= render :partial => '/widgets/vertical_widget',
               :object => item %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

to render about 20 items on a page (there's also another 20 of a different widget on the same page).

When I look at my server logs it's showing ~400ms per widget render, totaling out to ~20k ms for the page.  From what I've read using :colletion instead of a loop with :object should help to improve those times however I'm not sure how I can wrap each instance of the widget in an LI if I use :collection.  Not ever place the widget is used on the site is in a list so it doesn't make sense to include the LI in the widget code.

I could include the widget code directly in the loop rather than in a partial however I don't want to have to make code updates in multiple places.

Any other ideas to improve performance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give `content_tag` a try:

```
#some_file.html.erb

<ul>
<%= render :partial => 'widgets/vertical_widget', 
           :collection => @items, 
           :locals => { :wrap_in => :li } %>
</ul>



#/widgets/vertical_widget.html.erb

#First, render and capture the content once.
<% @rendered_content = capture do %>
  #render the item here
<% end %>

#Next, decide if the content rendered above should be wrapped in a tag or not
#If the "wrap_in" variable was passed-in and it is not nil/empty, then use that
#value for the tag; else do not wrap the content in a tag
<% if defined?(wrap_in) && !wrap_in.blank? %>
  <%= content_tag wrap_in do %>
    <%= @rendered_content %>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
    <%= @rendered_content %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I was kind of hoping for something outside of the partial, but I think this will still solve my problem.  I'll give it a try when I get home from work!

Comment: Well, you *could* do it using a spacer template (`:spacer => 'some_spacer_template_file'`) where you could render "open" tags (template would be `</li><li>` - note the "reversed" tags) - and then prepend a `<li>` and append a `</li>` in the collection render call - but that's "wrong" and ugly and might(?) cause other problems down the road.

Comment: Your code worked great, unfortunately my slowness problems persist.  Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is a late answer but it may be useful to people with similar questions.

Zabba's answer is very good and should help as a general guideline. However, your slowness problem is probably not to do with rendering. If a single render is taking 400ms, then it's likely that you are hitting the database repeatedly within the 'vertical_widget' partial. Check your logs for what queries are going on and see if you can cache any of that using a local variable.